# searchlogic returns nil when I order my records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, searchlogic

I can't figure out why ascend_by won't work for me.  Here's a console readout

`>> tapes = Tape.search(:timestamp_gte => "1278361923")

=> blah blah blah

>> tapes.length

=> 1436

>> tapes.ascend_by_timestamp

=> nil`

I get the same behavior when I use descend_by and other columns.

ruby 1.8.7
Rails 2.3.8
searchlogic 2.4.19

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'm not sure why, but it looks like it works if you add in the scope at the same time. But (oddly) only if the `ascend` part comes first. So:

```
tapes = Tape.ascend_by_id.search(:timestamp_gte => "1278361923")
```

should work, while

```
tapes = Tape.search(:timestamp_gte => "1278361923").ascend_by_id
```

doesn't.

Comment: That actually works perfectly for me, thanks!  I guess they changed the way ascend_by_* works :/